# Unable to display piechart on pivot screen (amchart-quickchart)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, charts, amcharts

I'm using amCharts-Quick-Charts to display piechart data but I cannot make it display on a pivot screen. The whole screen is just blank when I execute the program, is anyone able to help?

XAML code

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="Pie Chart">
    <Grid>
        <amq:PieChart x:Name="pie1" 
                      TitleMemberPath="title" 
                      ValueMemberPath="value"
                      >
        </amq:PieChart>
    </Grid>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

XAML.CS

```
namespace Project
{
    public partial class Humidity : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public Humidity()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public ObservableCollection<PData> Data = new ObservableCollection<PData>()  
        {  
            new PData() { title = "slice #1", value = 30 },  
            new PData() { title = "slice #2", value = 60 },  
            new PData() { title = "slice #3", value = 40 },  
            new PData() { title = "slice #4", value = 10 },  
        };  

        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
        {  
            pie1.DataSource = Data;  
        }  
    }  

    public class PData  
    {  
        public string title { get; set; }  
        public double value { get; set; }  
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you copied the code from [AmCharts-in-Windows-Phone](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/AmCharts-in-Windows-Phone-6de0d3c3)?  The project and code works just fine.  My guess is you pasted the code incorrectly.

Put a break point at

```
pie1.DataSource = Data;  // put a break point here
```

Does it break at that line?

If **NO** then you need to hook up the PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded by clicking on the event icon in the designer and setting the Loaded event to that specific function.

If **YES** then make sure nothing is covering and overriding the Chart inside your XAML.

---

Pivot Page example

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <phone:Pivot>
        <phone:PivotItem Header="one">
            <amq:PieChart x:Name="pie1" 
                      TitleMemberPath="title" 
                      ValueMemberPath="value">
            </amq:PieChart>
        </phone:PivotItem>
        <phone:PivotItem Header="two"></phone:PivotItem>
        <phone:PivotItem Header="three"></phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

---

If all is good it should look like this

[image]

Comment: Everything comes out except for the pie.
No issues when I do it on a new portrait page. Problem only comes in when I put it in a pivot page.

Comment: Then you're using the Pivot Page incorrectly, see updated solution.